# spec file: I want to use my tar

Tags: tar, rpm, aix, rpm-spec

On aix(and on unix usually..) the tar command doesn't play
good with some archives created with gnu tar.

I want to use my tar gnu on AIX

on .spec file I put this line

```
%define tar /opt/freeware/bin/tar
```

How to tell the `rpm -bb` command to use this tar and not tar of /usr/bin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found,after setup the var must
be added lines like this

```
%prep
%{tar} -xvf ../SOURCES/stunnel-%{version}.tar


%build
cd ../BUILD/stunnel-%{version}
if [ ! -x ./configure ]; then
    autoconf
    autoheader
fi

CFLAGS="%{optflags}" ./configure --prefix=%{_prefix} --sysconfdir=%{_sysconfdir}

%{__make}
```

In this case i use my tar specified 
with variable

```
%define tar /opt/freeware/bin/tar
```

on top of file.

Then must be tell to the spec how to find the root 
and builddir.